# Laravel Session File gigantic

Tags: file, laravel, session

I am using Laravel 5 for my web application,
since running it for over a week, the session are stored as files with over 9MB file size. Instead of the 1kb it used to be.

The CPU is running at 99% all the time and the server is not responding anymore. What causes this enormous file size and what do i need to do to reduce it?

Thanks!

Comment: What does it store in your session?

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the session settings in `config/session.php`, specifically the `lottery` setting might help you out.

You can also switch the session driver, if your system is unable to cope with the files. Depending on what you actually store in your sessions and the size of your application, it might be beneficial to switch to a different session driver. Avaiable options can be found here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#introduction